# How to line up the empty cells with filled cells for array of data structure?

Tags: latex

I'm trying to line up the empty cells with filled cells for an array in data structure. Please help!! This is the code I have so far:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes={draw, minimum size=8mm},
             nodes in empty cells,
             row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},]
{
  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
  2 & 4 & 4 & 5 &  &  &  & &\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It comes out look like this:[The boxes did not line up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI6gt.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI6gt.png)

I want to line up the boxes, how can I do that???

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried parsing 0 for cells 4-7 to see if not having a value is the issue? 
to mitigate i would recommend parsing something.. preferably null or ' ' if you wish to keep the boxes empty.

Comment: Yes, I tried null and ' ', the boxes still don't line up. It seems it only line up when I fill every box with a number, or all empty, or with all strings

Answer (score 0):

I first suggest that you post questions regarding LaTeX on [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

The fix to your problem is very simple! You are missing `anchor=center` in the `nodes={...}`.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes={draw, minimum size=8mm,anchor=center},
             nodes in empty cells, minimum height = 1cm,
             row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},]
{
  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7  \\
  2 & 4 & 4 & 5 &   &   &   &  & \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```